# How can Create Gap space between the box and The border above it?

Tags: html, css

How can Create Gap  space between the box and The border above it?

this is my html code :

```
    <section class="row productContentBox ">

<div class="col-7 bg-success  product-box ">


</div>


</section>
```

this is my css Code :

```
.productContentBox{
background: url("img/web/back1.png") #184e68 repeat;
border-top:solid 1px #cc3333;
border-bottom:solid 1px #cc3333;
height: 370px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need border on parent element along with padding to leave the space. Check Snippet.

```css
.productContentBox {
  border-top: solid 1px #cc3333;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #cc3333;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.product-box {
  background: url("img/web/back1.png") #184e68 repeat;
  height: 370px;
}
```

```html
<section class="row productContentBox ">

  <div class="col-7 bg-success  product-box ">

  </div>

</section>
```